# Panel/Hvplot interaction when variable is changing

Tags: python, holoviews, pyviz

I'm trying to create a dashboard with two holoviews objects: a [panel](https://panel.pyviz.org) `pn.widgets.Select` object that contains a list of xarray variables, and a [hvplot](https://hvplot.pyviz.org) object that takes the selected variable on input, like this:

```
def hvmesh(var=None):
    mesh = ds[var].hvplot.quadmesh(x='x', y='y', rasterize=True, crs=crs, 
       width=600, height=400, groupby=list(ds[var].dims[:-2]), cmap='jet')
    return mesh
```

Here's what an example mesh looks like for a particular variable (one that has both time and height dimensions):
[image]

I would like to have the map update when I select a variable from the panel widget:
[image]
I tried to do this as a dynamic map, like this:

```
from holoviews.streams import Params
import holoviews as hv

var_stream = Params(var_select, ['value'], rename={'value': 'var'})

mesh = hv.DynamicMap(hvmesh, streams=[var_stream])
```

but when I try to display the map, I get:

```
Exception: Nesting a DynamicMap inside a DynamicMap is not supported.
```

It would seem a common need to select the variable for hvplot from a panel widget.  What is the best way to accomplish this with [pyviz](http://pyviz.org)?

In case it's useful, here is my [full attempt Jupyter Notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/rsignell-usgs/f57428af32a46c2ba5fa7be86b3620e7).

Comment: I haven't tried running code like you have here, but  the first thing I'd try is to add `dynamic=False` to your `.quadmesh()` call, so that you aren't nesting multiple DynamicMaps.

Comment: If I add `dynamic=False` to the `.quadmesh()` call it seems to get stuck in some loop or something.  The kernel is busy, no error messages, but also no holoviews object returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `groupby` changes with each variable selected, a list of variables can not be passed to `hvplot`.  So one solution is to just recreate the plot each time a new variable is selected.  This works:

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews.streams import Params

def plot(var=None, tiles=None):
    var = var or var_select.value
    tiles = tiles or map_select.value
    mesh = ds[var].hvplot.quadmesh(x='x', y='y', rasterize=True, crs=crs, title=var,
                                   width=600, height=400, groupby=list(ds[var].dims[:-2]), 
                                   cmap='jet')
    return mesh.opts(alpha=0.7) * tiles

def on_var_select(event):
    var = event.obj.value
    col[-1] = plot(var=var)

def on_map_select(event):
    tiles = event.obj.value
    col[-1] = plot(tiles=tiles)

var_select.param.watch(on_var_select, parameter_names=['value']);
map_select.param.watch(on_map_select, parameter_names=['value']);

col = pn.Column(var_select, map_select, plot(var_select.value) * tiles)
```

producing:
[image]

Here is the [full notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/rsignell-usgs/073fd47dcd79647953d7814b253a89a9).

Comment: The link to the notebook seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

So there is a long answer and a short answer here. Let's start with the short answer, which is that there's no need to create a custom select widget for the data variable since hvPlot allows selecting between multiple data variables automatically, so if you change it to this:

```
rasterized_mesh = ds[time_vars].hvplot.quadmesh(
    x='x', y='y', z=time_vars[::-1], crs=crs, width=600, height=400, 
    groupby=list(ds[var].dims[:-2]), rasterize=True, cmap='jet')
```

[image]

You will get a DynamicMap that lets you select the non-spatial dimensions and the data variable and you can now embed that in your panel, no extra work needed. If that's all you care about **stop here** as we're about to get into some of the internals to hopefully deliver a better understanding.

Let us assume for a minute hvPlot did not allow selecting between data variables, what would we do then? So the main thing you have to know is that HoloViews allows chaining DynamicMaps but does not allow nesting them. This can be a bit hard to wrap your head around but we'll break the problem down into multiple steps and then see how we can achieve what we want. So what is the chain of events that would give us our plot?

1. Select a data variable
2. Apply a groupby over the non-spatial dimensions
3. Apply rasterization to each QuadMesh

As you know, hvPlot takes care of steps 2. and 3. for us, so how can we inject step 1. before 2. and 3. In future we plan to add support for passing panel widgets directly into hvPlot, which means you'll be able to do it all in a single step. Since panel is still a very new project I'll be pointing out along the way how our APIs will eventually make this process trivial, but for now we'll have to stick with the relatively verbose workaround. In this case we have to rearrange the order of operations:

1. Apply a groupby over the non-spatial dimensions
2. Select a data variable
3. Apply rasterization to each QuadMesh

To start with we therefore select **all** data variables and skip the rasterization:

```
meshes = ds[time_vars].hvplot.quadmesh(
    x='x', y='y', z=time_vars, crs=crs, width=600, height=400, 
    groupby=list(ds[var].dims[:-2]))
```

Now that we have a DynamicMap which contains all the data we might want to display we can apply the next operations. Here we will make use of the `hv.util.Dynamic` utility which can be used to chain operations on a DynamicMap while injecting stream values. In particular in this step we create a stream from the `var_select` widget which will be used to reindex the `QuadMesh` inside our meshes `DynamicMap`:

```
def select_var(obj, var):
    return obj.clone(vdims=[var])

var_stream = Params(var_select, ['value'], rename={'value': 'var'})
var_mesh = hv.util.Dynamic(meshes, operation=select_var, streams=[var_select])

# Note starting in hv 1.12 you'll be able to replace this with
# var_mesh = meshes.map(select_var, streams=[var_select])

# And once param 2.0 is out we intend to support
# var_mesh = meshes.map(select_var, var=var_select.param.value)
```

Now we have a DynamicMap which responds to changes in the widget but are not yet rasterizing it so we can apply the `rasterize` operation manually:

```
rasterized_mesh = rasterize(var_mesh).opts(cmap='jet', width=600, height=400)
```

Now we have a DynamicMap which is linked to the Selection widget, applies the groupby and is rasterized, which we can now embed in the panel. Another approach hinted at by @jbednar above would be to do all of it in one step by making the hvPlot call not dynamic and doing the time and height level selection manually. I won't go through that here but it also a valid (if less efficient) approach.

As I hinted at above, **eventually** we also intend to have all hvPlot parameters become dynamic, which means you'll be able to do something like this to link a widget value to a hvPlot keyword argument:

```
ds[time_vars].hvplot.quadmesh(
    x='x', y='y', z=var_select.param.value, rasterize=True, crs=crs,
    width=600, height=400, groupby=list(ds[var].dims[:-2]), cmap='jet')
```

Comment: @phillipejfr, the groupby needs to change with the variable selected, as different variables have different non-spatial dimensions.  Could that be accomplished with modifications of your short and long answers?

Comment: In that case it may be easier to use panel to rerender the plot entirely on variable changes, i.e. you could create a Row/Column container and when the variable selector changes you would replace the `objects` on the container.

Comment: The `mesh` object returned from `hvplot` displays fine, but `panel.Row(mesh)` returns `ValueError: Slider 'start' and 'end' cannot be equal`

Comment: I suppose we'll need a fix in ``panel`` to ensure constant dimensions are skipped when generating sliders, bokeh doesn't seem to allow it.